# Frobenius law in a monoidal category

Tags: ct.category-theory, frobenius-algebras

The Frobenius law for [Frobenius algebras](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Frobenius+algebra) in a monoidal category states that $$(\mu\otimes1)\circ(1\otimes\delta)=\delta\circ\mu=(1\otimes\mu)\circ(\delta\otimes1),$$
but this only makes sense in a strict monoidal category; for general monoidal categories we need to include the associators as illustrated by the following diagram

[image]

I'm learning about all this stuff for categorical quantum mechanics, so I'm wondering if this will be relevant or if it's safe to sweep under the rug. We have that any monoidal category is equivalent to a strict one as a special case of the coherence theorem for bicategories, so we could justify coherence-sweeping in the same way we do there, but I'm wondering if any physical intiution might be lost by making an appeal to a technical theorem like bicategorical coherence. Any assistance is appreciated.

As an aside, is the notion of a Frobenius algebra even well-defined in a lax monoidal category since we need the associator and its inverse for the Frobenius law?

Comment: I'm not sure and I don't know anything about physics, but mathematically it is safe to sweep it under the rug. A general rule of thumb is that associativity is usually safe (rectification results are very robust), whereas you do need to pay attention as soon as symmetry is involved.

Comment: I think it is worthwhile to note that, obviously, a correct definition of a Frobenius algebra in a weak monoidal category needs to involve the associator, just as suggested in the question.

Comment: Also, I would suggest to be careful about just ignoring associators. It depends on the monoidal category you are working with. For example, in the TQFT context, one considers the monoidal category of $G$-graded vector spaces twisted by a 3-cocycle on the group $G$. The 3-cocycle enters the definition of that category solely by modifying the associator. (However, in that example, it turns out that the associator $\alpha_{A,A,A}$, i.e., three times the same object, will be trivial; hence, for the definition of Frobenius algebras one can indeed ignore it.)